# How to access values in appsettings.json similiarly to accessing values in web.confi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, web-config, appsettings

Inn the way the web.config file can be accessed through using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` in asp.net, is there a way to access values in the appsettings.json file like so, without the need to use to inject any services ? I realize that the web.config file is no longer in use as much in .net core, I just wanted to know whether there was a similar method that could be used to access values from appsettings.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can also use the configuration directly, appsettings are injected so you can get to them with DI.

**Option 1**

You can try below code in the Program.cs(asp.net core 6+)  to access values from appsettings.json:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var vv = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("value");
...
```

In appsettings.json:

```
{"Value":"aaa"}
```

result:

[image]

**Option 2**

In your controller:

```
public class OPController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public OPController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var  vv = _configuration.GetSection("value").Get<string>();

        return View();
    }
  }
```

result:

[image]

You can read [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to know more.